# How to fix Error No adapter found for objects of type Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

We created a scrapy spider and would like to extract data using xpath as bellow

```
def parse(self, response):

    ldr = ItemLoader(item=JobItem, selector=response)
    ldr.add_xpath('job_title', '//div[@class="box intro"]//h1[@class="jobtitle truncate"]/text()')
    ldr.add_xpath('location', '//div[@class="box intro"]//span[@class="location"]/text()')
    ldr.add_xpath('company', '//div[@class="box intro"]//span[@class="company"]/text()')
    ldr.add_xpath('employment_type', '//div[@class="box intro"]//span[@class="employmenttype"]/text()')
    ldr.add_xpath('workload', '//div[@class="box intro"]//span[@class="workload"]/text()')
    ldr.add_xpath('industry', '//div[@class="box intro"]//span[@class="industry"]/text()')
    ldr.add_xpath('bewertung', '//div[@class="box intro"]//a[starts-with(@href, "https://www.kununu.com")]/span[0]/b/text()')
    ldr.add_value('direct_url', response.url)
    return ldr.load_item()
```

When running the spider we are facing following error:

```
TypeError: No adapter found for objects of type: <class 'scrapy.item.ItemMeta'> (<class 'Scrap100kJobs.items.JobItem'>)
```

Comment: post your item class code

Comment: `ItemLoader(item=JobItem, response=response)` and not `ItemLoader(item=JobItem, selector=response)`

Answer (score 3):

It should be `item=JobItem()` instead of `item=JobItem`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).